# Need help understanding difference between row creation methods

Tags: javascript

I am writing code to read from a file and write the contents of that into a table, and then do operations based on which row is clicked on.

I have created a jsfiddle that reads a file and creates rows but I'm having a hard time understanding how to select the correct rows.

http://jsfiddle.net/x1zjq3sv/4/

I am trying to select only rows (not  including the row in the header) of a table with a specific id.

I have tried to do:

```
var table = document.getElementById("TableID");
var tbod = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
var rows = tbod.getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

but the resulting variable 'tbod' seems to have no inner HTML, so the variable 'rows' is just empty. Can anyone explain why there appears to be nothing being selected?

Here's a sample input file:

input.txt:
http://pastebin.com/d4MqDiYW

Comment: You can get all the rows in a table using [*table.rows*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows) where *table* is a reference to a table. Table section elements such as *tbody*, *thead*, etc. have a similar property that is all the rows in the section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting everything properly, but too soon...

In your jsfiddle example, you have the following (pruned code to relevant parts):

```
document.getElementById('file').onchange = function() {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    // (create table rows...)
    // but this doesn't happen until the onload event is fired!
  }
  reader.readAsText(this.files[0]);
  addRowHandlers(); // reader.onload has been defined, but didn't fire yet!
}
```

So, all you would need to do, for example, is call `addRowHandlers()` *from* your onload handler:

```
...
reader.onload = function() {
  // (create table rows...)
  addRowHandlers(); // now there are rows to select :)
}
```

Comment: Oh, I thought that reader.readAsText(file) was the function causing the .onload function to be called. Looks like I'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

Simple, you should add the onclick event while creating row

```js
   document.getElementById('file').onchange = function(){

      var file = this.files[0];
      console.log(file);
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(progressEvent){

         //get rid of the old file's data before adding the data of the new file
         var new_tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
         var old_tbody = document.getElementById('TableID').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
         old_tbody.parentNode.replaceChild(new_tbody, old_tbody);

         // Process file line by line
         var lines = this.result.split('\n');
         for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){

            var col1 = 0;
            var col2 = 0;
            var col3 = 0;

            var tokens = lines[line].match(/\S+/g);

            if (tokens.length != 3) continue;
            if (tokens != null){
               col1 = tokens[0];
               col2 = tokens[1];
               col3 = tokens[2];
            }

            var tableRef = document.getElementById('TableID').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
            var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);
         var createClickHandler = function(row){
               return function() { 
                  var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                  var id = cell.innerHTML;
                  alert("id:" + id);
               };
         };
         newRow.onclick = createClickHandler(newRow);
            
            
            
            var col1Cell = newRow.insertCell(0);
            var col2Cell = newRow.insertCell(1);
            var col3Cell = newRow.insertCell(2);

            var col1CellText = document.createTextNode(col1);
            var col2CellText = document.createTextNode(col2);
            var col3CellText = document.createTextNode(col3);

            col1Cell.appendChild(col1CellText);
            col2Cell.appendChild(col2CellText);
            col3Cell.appendChild(col3CellText);
         }
      };
      reader.readAsText(file);
   };
```

```html
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">

<table id="TableID" border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```